# Counting total number of occurrences in selected (multiple) columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to summarize occurrences of categorical values in multiple columns, and as a result have a number of times that specific categorical value appeared in multiple columns.

Here's my dataframe:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': [1,2,3,4,5,6],
...                   'position_1':['abc', 'bbc', 'ccd', 'kpd', 'mne', 'jbp'],
...                   'position_2':['jkp', 'klp', 'abc', 'jbp', 'ccd', 'ppt'],
...                   'position_3':['abc', 'bbc', 'ytz', 'mne', 'ppt', 'jbp']})
>>> df
   user_id position_1 position_2 position_3
0        1        abc        jkp        abc
1        2        bbc        klp        bbc
2        3        ccd        abc        ytz
3        4        kpd        jbp        mne
4        5        mne        ccd        ppt
5        6        jbp        ppt        jbp
```

My desired output would look something like this:

```
value           number of occurrences in selected columns
abc                                 4
jbp                                 3
bbc                                 2
ccd                                 2
and so on.
```

I tried using value_counts, but I get a confusing result:

```
df.value_counts(['position_1', 'position_2', 'position_3'])

position_1  position_2  position_3
mne         ccd         ppt           1
kpd         jbp         mne           1
jbp         ppt         jbp           1
ccd         abc         ytz           1
bbc         klp         bbc           1
abc         jkp         abc           1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
cols = ['position_1', 'position_2', 'position_3'] 
df = df[cols].melt().groupby('value').size().reset_index(name='count')
print (df)
  value  count
0   abc      3
1   bbc      2
2   ccd      2
3   jbp      3
4   jkp      1
5   klp      1
6   kpd      1
7   mne      2
8   ppt      2
9   ytz      1
```

Answer (score 3):

Apply [value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) to each column and [sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) along the second axis:

```
res = df[['position_1', 'position_2', 'position_3']].apply(pd.Series.value_counts).fillna(0).sum(1).astype(int)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
abc    3
bbc    2
ccd    2
jbp    3
jkp    1
klp    1
kpd    1
mne    2
ppt    2
ytz    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the methods [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html#pandas.DataFrame.value_counts):

```
df.filter(like='position', axis=1).melt().value_counts('value')
```

Output:

```
abc    3
jbp    3
ppt    2
bbc    2
ccd    2
mne    2
ytz    1
kpd    1
klp    1
jkp    1
Name: value, dtype: int64
```